# Know when a function is finished proccessing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a screen capture but I want to not include certain canvas. i tried the code below but canvasses are still included in the capture. how to know when the screencapture function has finish before executing the next line of code?

```
void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                GameManager.Instance.memeButton.SetActive(false);
                ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("C:/Users/jamjam/dwhelper/Desktop/test/jamjam.png");
                GameManager.Instance.memeButton.SetActive(true);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Screenshots are most likely captured at the end of Update, when rendering finished. So you can try to re-activate the buttons on the next frame.

Comment: Thanks for answer but unfortunately not working. seems like ScreenCapture is running in seperate thread and continue executing the rest of the code.

Comment: See [`ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html):  `The CaptureScreenshot returns immediately on Android. The screen capture continues in the background. The resulting screen shot is saved in the file system after a few seconds.`

Comment: It has to run at the end of the frame, you cannot get half-rendered frames and there is never a delay. The frame you call "CaptureScreenshot" on, is the frame on which the screenshot will be taken (at the end). I would use a bool variable like "reactivate_buttons" that will call `setActive` on the next frame. Not LateUpdate, the real next frame. If the buttons still show up, then verify that "SetActive(false)" actually hides them from the screenshot by *not* calling "SetActive(true)" just to make sure.

Comment: @derHugo is there a way to know when it has finish saving a file before continue executing the next code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html)

> The `CaptureScreenshot` returns immediately on Android. The screen capture continues in the background. The resulting screen shot is saved in the file system after a few seconds.

=> There is no information really how it behaves on a PC. So basically there is no build-in way to know when it is finished which is valid on all platforms ... you could however build a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for checking that like e.g.

```
private bool alreadyTakingScreenshot;

void Update()
{
    if (!alreadyTakingScreenshot && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        // Start a new routine
        StartCoroutine(ScreenshotRoutine);
    }   
}

// or in case you do NOT want the GUI to appear in your screenshot (see comment in ScreenshotRoutine)
//void LateUpdate()
//{
//    if (!alreadyTakingScreenshot && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
//    {
//        // Start a new routine
//        StartCoroutine(ScreenshotRoutine);
//    }   
//}

private void IEnumerator ScreenshotRoutine()
{
    if(alreadyTakingScreenshot) yield break;

    alreadyTakingScreenshot = true;

    GameManager.Instance.memeButton.SetActive(false);

    // It is convenient to wait until the end of the frame which is right
    // before the frame is rendered by the camera
    // If you don't want the GUI to appear in your screenshot then
    // remove this and rather start the routine from LateUpdate
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    

    // Use a timestamp so everytime a new image is created
    var dateStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M_HH-mm-ss");
    var path = @"C:/Users/jamjam/dwhelper/Desktop/test/jamjam_" + dateStamp + ".png";

    // Or alternatively simply delete the exsting file as you will overwrite it
    //var path = @"C:/Users/jamjam/dwhelper/Desktop/test/jamjam.png"
    //if(!File.Exists(path))
    //{
    //   File.Delete(path);    
    //}

    // start the capture
    ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(path);

    // Wait until the according file is actually created
    while(!File.Exists(path))
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    GameManager.Instance.memeButton.SetActive(true);

    alreadyTakingScreenshot = false;
}
```

Comment: However, OP didn't want the buttons to show up in the screenshot. The screenshot is most likely taken at end of frame, only the file write operation is taking a bit longer.

Comment: What if the file already exist from the previous screenshot the yield will not return.?

Comment: It has a new name every time since I added a timestamp ... it will not exist ... if you really want the name to be the same then simply first delete the existing file, updated the code

Comment: @KYL3R well worst that can happen with this solution is that the `GameManager.Instance.memeButton` stays one frame longer inactive than neccessary ... but like this it also works for Android. For GUI part you could simply skip the `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();` and instead start the routine from `LateUpdate`